# How to dynamically update your UITableView when a button is pressed?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm stuck with a seemingly very simple app that I'm trying to develop

Basically, I have a UITable, and two buttons: red/blue

When a button is pressed, a row with corresponding title of that button is append to the table

[image]

I'm overwhelmed by how complicated UITableView has to be implemented (datasource, delegate, resuable identifier, etc)

Can anyone help me out with this, preferably show me detailed codes

For my Buttons, I have something like this

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSString *item = sender.currentTitle;
    [self.cellArray addObject:item];
    [self.myTable reloadData];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.cellArray.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"The Table Cell";

   self.myTableCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (self.myTableCell == nil) {
       self.myTableCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
   self.myTableCell.textLabel.text = [self.cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return self.myTableCell;
}
```

Comment: what have you done so far?? add some code, that you have written for tableview delegate methods. You just need to update the data sources and then call [yourtable reloadData]

Comment: honestly, I have no idea where to start, where do I write the delegate and datasource? I'm complete nub with these terms. I checked some tutorial, but they are all about UITableViewController which will be called later into the view. But my app required my UITableView object to stay in my view and dynamically update itself in which case I dont think I should create a new UITableViewController class to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are learning this..i will post a simple solution.
Make add a member variable `NSMutableArray *cellArrays`;

initialize it in your `viewDidLoad`

in `buttonPressed` check;

```
if([@"red" isEqualToString:[YourButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]])
{
 [self.cellArrays addObject:@"red"];
}
else
{
 [self.cellArrays addObject:@"blue"];
}
[self.YOURTABLEVIEW reloadData];
```

Now in your table view datasource method

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.cellArrays.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
 //in between your code;
 YOURCELL.textlabel.text = [self.cellArrays objectAtIndex : indexpath.row];
}
```

Try this ..

Comment: That looks very much like what i'm looking for, /hug. Can I put datasource method in my rootviewcontroller.m?

Comment: yes.. but you will still need a table view in your view controller..llok up tutorials on how to create iboutlets on youtube

Comment: I ctrl dragged both UITableView and UITableCell to my .h file to give them a variable name, so I assume I can replace YOURTABLEVIEW and YOURCELL with those names right?

Comment: One more thing, the compiler shows a warning says no reusable identifier. what exactly is taht?

Comment: neverheard no reusable identifier..on which line it is??? also you  have to use your variable names instead of mine YOUR ones...also make sure your view controller is the delegate and datasource of the tableview.

Comment: I have edited my code in the question, but I guess I have to set the datasource and delegate. Again, where should I implement these two?

Comment: search youtube on UITableView tutorial...you will definitely come across at least one tutorial that will show how to setup delegate and datasource correctly...

Comment: I watched many tutorials but most of them is about creating a UITableViewController instead of how to play with UITableView Object. Is it possible to declare delegate in my rootViewController and link it to the tableView in my UI?

Comment: yes..it is possible ...okay look for resigning UITextField on return on youtube...that will show you how to use delegates and hook them up..you can use that information to work with tableview

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend subclassing UITableViewController, then override the dataSource and delegate methods and you should be good to go. Going straight to UITableView is more complicated without any obvious benefits.

You may not be using Core Data, but I still recommend this lecture because it hooks up a TableViewController and works great - all code included.  Check it out:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/289

The lectures in iTunes U explain everything further.

Enjoy,

Damien

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that "One more thing, the compiler shows a warning says no reusable identifier. what exactly is that?" above...

His answer is correct, but to get rid of that compiler warning...

The tableviewcell of your tableview has to have an identifier.  In IOS 5, in your storyboard, highlight the TableViewCell in your TableView, and enter a value in the Identifier. This must match the value in your code of the cell that you are creating.